# How to encode a video at 30 FPS from images taken at 7 FPS

Tags: ffmpeg

I have no knowledge whatsoever about video encoding, I have an application written in OpenGL and I am saving the frames it generated into `png` images. The frames from my app are at 7 FPS and I am trying to create a video from those.

To that purpose I use ffmpeg like this

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4`

which was taken [from this site](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images), however I was wondering if it is possible to have a video that shows the animation at 30 FPS?

Comment: [Similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012113/how-to-make-video-out-of-frames-with-a-given-frame-rate) and [manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ffmpeg.1.html).

Comment: Just tweak the `-framerate` parameter to get the desired results.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm using the below code to do the same thing.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%03d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 output.mp4
```

Breaking down the command:

```
ffmpeg             <- call ffmpeg
  -framerate 30    <- set the input framerate to 30
  -i img%03d.png   <- read PNG images with filename img001, img002, img003, etc..
                     img can be changed to another prefix
                     %03d can be changed to %04d for 0001, %05d for 00001 formats, etc...
  -c:v libx264     <- Set the codec to libx264
  -pix_fmt yuv420p <- Set the pixel format to planar YUV 4:2:0, 12bpp
  -crf 23          <- set the Constant Rate Factor to 23 (default value)
  -output.mp4      <- the output filename
```

This reads the input at 30 fps (the `-framerate 30` option) and encodes it using the `libx264` codec with [constant rate factor](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf) of 23 (the `-crf 23` option).

Comment: How do you compute the `-crf` value? What does it represent compared to the 30 fps and 7 frames per second in the source? (i.e. is it "30 - 7 = 23"?)

Comment: It's not related to the fps (I think). Did you read the linked page about the constant rate factor (crf)?

Comment: Oh, yeah, so I really don't understand how your answer was chosen as the answer. It's wrong. In OP's question, the input FPS is 7 and the output 30. You are not taking care of that in your examples.

Comment: Thanks for trying to improve my answer. I don't entirely follow, Could you perhaps explain what is not being addressed? The question asker wants a video that plays 30 of their frames per second. The command in my answer outputs 30 frames per second. The framerate at which the frames are captured (7) seems not relevant, right?

Comment: Assuming you count from 1, frames 1 to 7 from the input have to be played in 1 second (spread over 30 frames in the output video). Then frames 8 to 15 will be played on the 2nd second of the output video. Etc. I think that with your command line you will end up playing 30 frames of input in 1 second (a little over 4 times too fast).

Comment: That's certainly one way to interpret it, but the question asker did not specify that that's what they want, so I gave an answer based on my interpretation. As the question asker did not post comments (e.g. "it's playing way too fast now") and accepted the answer it appears the answer was helpful (to some extent). Feel free to edit my answer if you believe it displays incorrect information or post your own answer if you would like to obtain reputation points.

Answer (score 36):

## Image inputs

Default frame rate for image inputs is 25. You can change it with the `-framerate` input option. Example for 24 fps:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i input_%03d.jpg -vf format=yuv420p output.mp4
```

- `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the legacy alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) will ensure compatible [chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) for MP4. Otherwise, `ffmpeg` will try to preserve color fidelity, but most players can't handle advanced chroma subsampling.
- The output will use the same frame rate as the input. So you do not need to set an output frame rate. But there are a few reasons to do so. See *Using a different frame rate for image inputs and video output* below.

## Video inputs

Use the `-r` output option:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 25 output.mp4
```

---

### Using a different frame rate for image inputs and video output

Why? For example, you may want all images to be displayed for 1 second each (1 fps). But most players can't play very low frame rates (about 6 fps or lower). So you can make `ffmpeg` use a different output frame rate. The output will look like 1 fps, but will actually be a normal frame rate, such as 25 fps.

Example: input images at 1 fps, but make the output 25 fps.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i input_%03d.png -r 25 output.mp4
```

- Frames will be duplicated or dropped to match the desired output frame rate.
- The [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) uses `-framerate`, while the output frame rate is set using `-r`.

#### Error: Option framerate not found

The `-framerate` option:

- Is not a generic option. It doesn't work for everything.
- Is only an input option.
- Only works with certain [demuxers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) (including: images, x11grab, rawvideo).
- You probably only need to use the `-r` output option. See the *Video inputs* section above.

Comment: ffmpeg version 3.2.2 tells me: `Option framerate not found.` :-(

Comment: Yes, you are right. But nevertheless the option `-framerate` does not exist anymore. I will delete my comment, as it really has nothing to do with converting a series of images to a video with a certain framerate.

Comment: @erik `-framerate` does exist. It's used by the image and rawvideo demuxers and some input devices such as x11grab and v4l2.

Comment: Oh, ok. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: Where is the option `-framerate` documented? I've read the `man ffmpeg` page, but I couldn't find it. Any pointer, perhaps?

Comment: OK, found it... `FFMPEG-DEVICES(1)`.

Comment: For MP4 to MP4 conversion, `ffmpeg -y -i in.mp4 -r 30 out.mp4` just worked. `-framerate` seems to not work in this case.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `-framerate` is not a generic option. It is a special input option only for certain demuxers: image inputs, some capturing inputs such as x11grab and v4l2 and a few others. The original question was about images, so that's why the answer involves `-framerate`, although it seems like many users are not noticing this. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i img%03d.png output.mp4
```

will be sufficient in the latest version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Dont forget the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` or you may end up with files that many software tools don't like: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8856

Comment: I don't see how that would be sufficient since the input is at 7 fps. That frame rate has to appear somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about video interpolation. There is no way for 7 fps to become 30 fps without video interpolation... Basically you want to get 30fps from the start, in the process of making videos... As video interpolation will take lots of resources and time, and it might be filled with artifacts. I heard you can make a single shot picture into a short movies, with adobe, but lots of manual work there...

Comment: Ah, sure there is. Modern neuronal networks can do a lot of fun things along these lines, cf. https://www.youtube.com/c/DenisShiryaev/videos

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may the resultant video to have 30 frames per second for compatibility with certain devices (e.g. a DVD player), but you want the content to play back at an effective 7 frames per second to maintain the original temporal resolution. In that case, you'll need to use an FFmpeg video filter like [tblend](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178503/ffmpeg-interpolate-frames-or-add-motion-blur) or [minterpolate](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/herifq/minterpolate_to_reduce_image_sequence_framerate/) to interpolate the 7 frames' worth of content to 30 frames (with varying visual changes), or use a third party application like [butterflow](https://github.com/dthpham/butterflow) which itself uses FFmpeg.

If you purely want the 7 fps source content to be sped up to 30 fps (shortening the playback time ~4:1) then the other `-framerate` based answers will suffice.